# How to trigger a button click event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in VS using C# and I need to trigger a button using Enter key from a textbox. I don't know if it is possible, and if it's not, then I'd like to hear some alternatives for that.

I've already tried something with KeyDown and KeyUp because I saw it here, but it doesn't work or I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `KeyDown` event of the TextBox trapping the Enter key and clicking button1:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }
}
```